# swapping values in multi-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

im currently working on a problem where i need to swap the values in the multi-dimensional array based on a condition. example of the inputs:

```
2 3

4 5

5 2

6 25
```

the above elements are in a array of 4 rows and 2 columns (columns = 2 is fixed).
If the value is column is greater than value in the row, then nothing has to be changed, else the values should be interchanged.

please find my code below:

```
int c = 2;
int temp1, temp2;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter 'n': ");
n = in.nextInt();

int[][] arr = new int[n][c];

if (n <= 15) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            System.out.println("Enter values into md-array: ");
            arr[i][j] = in.nextInt();
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] < arr[i][j + 1]) {
                System.out.println(arr[i][j]);
            } else {
                temp2 = i; //swapping
                i = j;
                j = temp2;

                temp1 = j;
                j = i;
                i = temp1;

                System.out.println(arr[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm trying out with the above code, I could write the elements into the array but I'm not able to perform the swap operation nor the initial compare operation. I'm also facing the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. I'm not able to rectify this.

Comment: you are swapping index not value.

Comment: when im referring the index, the value will be changed right .. please correct me if im wrong

Comment: No, you have to mention array value not index itself. i'll check and post correct code.

Comment: please let me know what mistake ive actually done so that i can correct myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    int c=2;
        int temp1, temp2;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 'n': ");
        int n = in.nextInt();

        int[ ][ ] arr = new int[n][c];

        if (n<=15) {
            for(int i=0; i<n;i++) {
                for (int j=0;j<c;j++) {
                    System.out.println("Enter values into md-array: ");
                    arr[i][j]=in.nextInt();
                    }   
            }
            System.out.println("====================================================");
            for(int i[]: arr){
                for(int j: i){
                    System.out.print(j+"   ");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            System.out.println("====================================================");
            for(int i=0; i<n;i++) {
                for (int j=0;j<c-1;j++) {
                  if (arr[i][j]<arr[i][j+1]) {
//                      System.out.println(arr[i][j]);      
                  }
                  else {
                      temp2=arr[i][j]; //swapping
                      arr[i][j]=arr[i][j+1];
                      arr[i][j+1]=temp2;

//                      System.out.println(arr[i][j]);
                  }
                }
            }
            for(int i[]: arr){
                for(int j: i){
                    System.out.print(j+"   ");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
```

Now check. i have checked it working. Sample data i have entered is :

```
3   4   
4   4   
5   3   
1   7
```

and out is :

```
3   4   
4   4   
3   5   
1   7
```

Comment: its not working.. IndexOutOfBoundsException at arr[i][j+1]=temp2;

Comment: else {
                       temp2=arr[i][j]; //swapping
                       arr[i][j]=arr[i][j+1];
                       arr[i][j+1]=temp2;
                       System.out.println(arr[i][j]);
                   }  but this is not giving the correct output.. ive tried it like the above

Comment: Now check. i have checked it working. Sample data i have entered is : 3   4   
4   4   
5   3   
1   7    and out is : 3   4   
4   4   
3   5   
1   7

Comment: its working now.. but what was that u have changed, ive noticed a change in the swap statement, which i understood.. what is that last for loop used for ?

Comment: enhanced loops are used before and after swapping just to check the output.

Comment: yes now i understood. the mistake i did was swapping the index instead of values. thanks for the help @Manoj Sharma :)

Comment: Its my pleasure to help anyone who is helpless in java and i know how to do.

Comment: Manoj, a small query, what if i what to arrange the swapped numbers in the increasing or decreasing order with respect to the second number. how should i go about ?. what i thought of is putting them in a list and reverse sort them using collections. but that ain't working.. any other way ? can u help

Comment: you need to implement sorting algorithms like bubble, quick, merge to make an order in your code. if you want to use collection then you don't need to put sorting algorithms. it will be done by collection it self depending what type of collection you are going to use.